# How do I write this program to include the last letter of the string?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "Hello There";
        String p = "eo";
        int reps = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<s.length()-p.length(); i++) //checks all characters in the length of s.length minus the length it's searching for
        {

            for (int j=0; j<p.length(); j++)
            {
                if (s.charAt(i+j) == p.charAt(j)) 
                    reps++; 
            }


        }

        System.out.print(reps);

    }
```

It's printing 3 for the amount of times e and o appear, when it should be printing 4. I've figured that it's because it's ending the search after checking "re", which would mean it checked "r" for "e", and "e" for "o." This would normally work but the search ends here and I get out of range errors if I try to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looping the whole first string.

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length()-p.length(); i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
```

..

```
String s = "Hello There";  //length is 11
String p = "eo"; // length is 2
```

If you loop all the characters of the first string its ok, but you are looping s.length-p.length, there you are reading the first 11-2 characters (and one of the finds is the last one, in the position length-1)

```
if (s.charAt(i+j) == p.charAt(j))
```

That should be

```
if (s.charAt(i) == p.charAt(j))
```

You want to compare every char of p in s

If you are comparing "H" with "eo", you want to compare "H" with "e" and then with "o", if you use i+j it will move the pointer of "H" to "e" and so on.

Comment: This presents an out of range error.

Nevermind, your edit fixed it. I don't know why I even had that j in s.charAt anyway. I'm dumb, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing

```
for (int i=0; i<s.length()-p.length(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
```

Basically, you condition is saying while `i < 10 - 2` which isn't what you want to do.  Instead, you want to check every character in `s`

Next, change...

```
if (s.charAt(i+j) == p.charAt(j))
```

to

```
if (s.charAt(i) == p.charAt(j)) {
```

Otherwise you won't be checking the right character and may end up with an array out of bounds exception...

If `i` == `0` then you loop will be checking the character at `i` (`0`) and `i+j` (`1`) which isn't really what you want.  You only want to compare the characte at `i`

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < p.length(); j++)
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) == p.charAt(j)) {
            reps++; 
        }
    }
}
```

You were getting an *out of range* error because you were checking for `s.charAt(i+j)` when you should be checking for `s.charAt(i)`.